# Static Library Issues in ios (cant find header files)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to create a static library by taking help from [this site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial).

A problem i encountered is that i deleted the initial classes that xcode had setup for me.
If the name of the project is XYZ, xcode had created xyz.h and xyz.m
I deleted those and created new classes ABC.h and .m.

Now when i build the code I cant find the include folder in derived data > build >products.
I dont know if I am doing something foolish here, but is there a way to tell xcode that ABC.h is my new main header file.

Please Enlighten me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your build phases for your target? Specifically, the "Copy Headers" build phase, if it exists.

Comment: Thanks A ton @craig otis. That was the issue. i added the .h file into the "copy files" section in "build phases" and then built the code the include folder is now present. Can you please post it as answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every header file that you want distributed (and publicly available) as part of your static library needs to be specified in the "Copy Headers" build phase of your target.

See this link for screenshots and good tips:

http://rheard.com/blog/creating-static-ios-libraries/

The critical screenshot from that page:

[image]